# Bash script to to subtract values from corresponding lines contained in variables

Tags: bash, awk

I don't think this has been asked: I have been working on a small bash script to pull down some data and my idea was to have it compare today's data from yesterday's to find usage.

`Today`'s file looks like:

```
150
100
50
```

`Yesterday`'s file looks like:

```
145
99
20
```

I am looking for something that will subtract line1 from `Today` from `Yesterday` *when the contents of both files are stored in variables of the same name* and print out the result.

```
Total
5
1
30
```

From the command line with files, it works, but from the script, which reads the contents of variables holding the data, it prints out the first `cat` and then can't find the file:

```
cat file1 | awk '{n=$0; getline < "file2"; print" " n-$0}'
5
1
30
WORKS

cat $Today | awk '{n=$0; getline < "$Yesterday"; print" " n-$0}'
cat: 5: No such file or directory
cat: 1: No such file or directory
cat: 30: No such file or directory
```

Any idea?

Comment: Your error message suggests that `$Today` doesn't actually contain a _filename_, but the string `'5 1 30'`

Comment: With the benefit of hindsight and for that of future readers: The OP is confused about the distinction between providing input via _file names_ (`file1`) and via _variables containing data_ (`$Today`, `$Yesterday`) - the error message stated stems from misusing a data variable as if it were a filename. An additional problem is the ineffective reference to _shell_ variable `$Yesterday` in the _single-quoted_ `awk` program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see this is tagged [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), but alternatively you could use `bc`.  Here `Today` and `Yesterday` are filenames containing your data:

```
$ echo Total; paste -d- Today Yesterday | bc
Total
5
1
30
$
```

---

**Update**

Since we now know that `$Today` and `$Yesterday` are bash variables containing newline-separated lists, here's another way to achieve what you need, which just uses bash built-in functionality.  Not needing to spawn external processes (`awk`, `paste`, `bc`, etc) will improve performance if you have a large data set.

```
# Create array versions of the variables
TodayArr=($Today)
YesterdayArr=($Yesterday)

# Loop over the list of indices in the Today array and do bash-based arithmetic
for i in ${!TodayArr[@]}; do
    echo $(( ${TodayArr[$i]} - ${YesterdayArr[$i]} ))
done
```

The caveat to the above is that bash built-in arithmetic `$((  ))` only handles integers (typically 64bit signed).  If your values contain decimals, then you'd have to use `bc` again or one of the awk solutions.  The `for` loop would look something like this:

```
# Loop over the list of indices in the Today array and do bc-based arithmetic
for i in ${!TodayArr[@]}; do
    echo "${TodayArr[$i]} - ${YesterdayArr[$i]}"
done | bc
```

Comment: +1; great simplifcation; `-d-` is the same as `-d '-'` and inserts a `-` between the two values (from the corresponding lines of the input files), resulting in a subtraction expression that `bc` then evaluates.

Comment: I tried this and replaced Today and Yesterday with my $Today and $Yesterday that I define out earlier in the script and when I run it I get<br> paste: 5406: No such file or directory<br>
5406 is the first line of $Today but that is all I get with that error.

Comment: Re bash-only solution: If you use process substitution, as in the accepted answer, you only need a _single_ external command (line), and the external utilities do the heavy lifting of looping over all lines. Turns out that that is much, much faster than looping in `bash`: about 30-60x times faster on my machine, depending on which external solution is used. (On a side note: I recently noticed that array subscripts are evaluated in an _arithmetic_ context, which means you don't need the `$` prefix to refer to variables: `[i]` is sufficient (though `[$i]` obviously works)).

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: This answer is based on the assumption that `$Today` and `$Yesterday` refer to *files*, as in the OP's command-line example; turns out these variables actually contain *data*.

However, this answer still correctly explains an *additional* problem: the mistaken reference to a *shell* variable inside the *single-quoted* `awk` program.

It also provides a simpler (and as it turns out: faster - thanks, JS웃) alternative to the command using both `paste` and `awk`.

---

`$Yesterday` won't be expanded inside your `awk` program, because the `awk` program as a whole is enclosed in *single* quotes, which means that any shell variable references in it are NOT expanded.

To pass shell variable values into an `awk` program, use the `-v varName=varValue` option:

```
cat "$Today" | awk -v Yesterday="$Yesterday" '{n=$0; getline < Yesterday; print" " n-$0}'
```

- `-v Yesterday="$Yesterday"` defines **`awk`** variable `Yesterday`, which can then be used as is (no quoting, no `$` prefix) inside the `awk` program.

---

Alternatively, you can combine `paste` with `awk`:

```
paste file1 file2 | awk '{ print $1 - $2 }'
```

- `paste` merges the corresponding lines from `file1` and `file2`, which `awk` can then easily parse and perform arithmetic on.

Comment: Unfortunately that did almost the same thing. From command line using the file name it works however in the bash script using a argument I get paste: 5406: No such file or directory

Comment: @user3546681: Are you running the script from the same directory? If you change to absolute paths, does it work then? Are variables `$Today` and `$Yesterday` actually set?

Comment: @user3546681: Your error message suggests that `$Today` doesn't actually contain a _filename_, but the _string_ `5 1 30`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way with `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}{print $1-a[FNR]}' yesterdaysfile todaysfile
5
1
30
```

- Read through yesterdaysfile in to an array indexed at line number `NR`.
- Once the entire file is read, you subtract the todays file with the array using line number `FNR`.

`NR` and `FNR` are a variables that stores line number with the difference being `FNR` gets reset to `1` when a new file is read. `NR` does not. So using them wisely can get you the result you seek.

#### Performance check:

```
$ seq 10000000 > f1

$ seq 10000000 > f2

$ time paste f1 f2 | awk '{ print $1 - $2 }' >/dev/null

real    0m12.894s
user    0m13.519s
sys     0m0.229s

$ time cat f1 | awk '{n=$0; getline < "f2"; print" " n-$0}' >/dev/null

real    0m14.615s
user    0m14.428s
sys     0m0.154s

$ time awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next}{print $1-a[FNR]}' f1 f2 >/dev/null

real    0m18.631s
user    0m17.459s
sys     0m1.094s

$ time paste -d- f1 f2 | bc >/dev/null

real    0m37.221s
user    0m32.027s
sys     0m6.535s
```

Comment: The OP's own approach based on `getline` strikes me as superior in this case (his/her incidental problems notwithstanding), because it doesn't require storing all lines from the first file in memory first.

Comment: @mklement0 True, performance wise, your solution turned out to be the fastest. I added some test output in the answer. `+1` to your answer. `:)`

Comment: Cool, thanks for testing (+1 for that)! I would not have expected the `bc` solution to be so slow. Any idea why?

Comment: @mklement0 My money is on the time spent on loading the library for each iteration and parsing the input line to check for operand to perform mathematical calculation. This could vary on different flavors and/or compile time optimization.

Comment: @JS웃 Which library are you referring to?  The `bc` process is only spawned once in this pipeline.  I guess `bc` is just slow at parsing each line.

Comment: @DigitalTrauma You are right, they were just my guesses. I was referring about the math library which it imports during launch. Also, wasn't sure if the `pipe` could cause a lag in filling the buffer first and then handing it over to `bc`.

Comment: @JS웃 The pipe will cause some small delay when compared with a single-process solution, as there will necessarily be context switches as the processes either side of the pipe are scheduled.  A larger pipe buffer should increase performance as fewer context switches are required.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `$Today` and `$Yesterday` contain *data* or perhaps *file contents*, not file names, if you want to use your code, you can do:

```
$ awk '{n=$1; getline < ARGV[2]; print" " n-$1}' <(echo "$Today") <(echo "$Yesterday")
 5
 1
 30
awk: warning: close of fd 62 (`/dev/fd/62') failed (Bad file descriptor)
```

But as you can see, you'll get a warning with *gawk*. As noted in the comments by [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0), you can safely ignore this warning by adding `2>/dev/null` at the end, but only after you are sure it works as you want. Otherwise you may be missing some important debugging information.

A more idiomatic way would be:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN  { print "Total"}
    NR == FNR { n[FNR] = $1;next} 
    NF        { print n[FNR] - $1 }' <(echo "$Today") <(echo "$Yesterday") 
Total
5
1
30
```

Comment: That got it... Printed out perfectly.  Thanks

Comment: +1 for rearranging the first statement based on `ARGV[2]`. The warning  - which should be considered a bug - seems to affect only *GNU* `awk`; neither `mawk` nor FreeBSD `awk` show it. Since even with GNU `awk` the exit code is still `0`, simply suppressing stderr with `2>/dev/null` will do - and is worth doing, given that this solution is superior to the 2nd.

Comment: @mklement0 thanks for looking into it. I thought it was just a consequence of abusing `ARGV`, but really it should be no different to using the actual file name. I didn't have enough brain power at the time to think about it much.

Comment: Your use of `ARGV` is fine - process substitution actually yields _filenames_ - such as the one from the warning, `/dev/fd/62`. However, these files _are_ special in that they are _named pipes_ (FIFOs) - how  exactly dealing with them differs from normal files, I don't know, but calling `close()` on them _should_ work. (And thanks for mentioning me in your update.)